# How to pass data on the root components in Vue

Tags: vue.js

How can I pass the `page_id` to the `Sidebar` component method `highlightNode()`, because I want to highlight a newly added item. My current code is the page id is undefined.

This is my code & structure.

my root component is `Sidebar.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="page in pages">
                <div :class="{ 'highlight': highlightedNode == page.id }">
                    <router-link :to="'/view/' + page.id" @click.native="highlightNode(page.id)">
                        <span v-title="page.title"></span>
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            pages: [],
            highlightedNode: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getPages()
        this.$root.$refs.Sidebar = this
    },
    methods: {
        getPages() {
            axios.get('/get-pages').then(response => {
                this.pages = response.data
            });
        },
        highlightNode(id) {
            this.highlightedNode = id
        },
    }
}
```

my add new Page component `AddNewPage.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="main-header">
            <div class="page-title">
                <input type="text" v-model="page.title" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-footer text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="saveChanges()">Save and Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</template>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            page: {
                title: null,
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        //
    },
    methods: {
         saveChanges() {
            axios.post('/store-new-filter', this.page)
            .then(response => {
                const id = response.data.id // return page id
                this.$root.$refs.Sidebar.highlightNode(id) // <-- this line, I want to pass page id to hightlight the newly added page.
            })
            .catch( error => {
               
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Or any alternative way to achieve my expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You design/architecture looks a little strange to me, but I only see a limited part of your app.  Try making SideBar a child of Page and passing data as props.

Comment: Your component should emit an event like `$emit("new-page", id)` for example, so you can listen from the parent and act in the value! Take a look at vuejs emit event.

Comment: @Marky Parent/child component relationships, as well as the props/event model are very important to understand when using Vue.  I suggest doing more reading and tutorials.